# Colocar várias variáveis em um alert()

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer um alert "formatado", algo como:

Preço: variável X.

Nome do produto: variavel Y

Descrição: variável Z

Mas não acho em nenhuma documentação como fazer tal "formatação", tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
buttonBuy.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("Comprar:" + name, "Preço" + preco,"Quantidade de Unidades" + quantidadeunidades.value,"Quantidade de Caixas" + quantidadecaixas.value);
  });
```

Comment: Não foi muito claro o que você realmente quer? Como assim formatado?

Comment: Por exemplo, aparecer a palavra Nome, e dps dela a variável X, ai na outra linha a palavra Preço, e a variável Y.

Comment: Ah! Você quer concatenar strings.

Comment: Acredito que o que ele no caso é formatar um string.

Comment: Se for isso por favor atualize a pergunta. ter um pergunta bem formulada ajuda a outras pessoas que tem o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

**Se foi o que entendi, você quer concatenar strings.**

> Em javascript, há várias formas de se fazer isso, por exemplo, a forma tradicional é usar o símbolo **+**. Usando seu raciocínio, tente:

```js
let buttonBuy = document.getElementById("myButton");

var quantidadeunidades = {
value:1
}

var quantidadecaixas = {
value:1
}

buttonBuy.addEventListener("click", () => {
let name= "nome";
let preco = 45.5;
let quantidade =  quantidadeunidades.value;
let quantCaixas = quantidadecaixas.value;
    alert("Comprar:" + name + "\nPreço: " + preco + "\nQuantidade de Unidades: " + quantidade  + "\nQuantidade de Caixas: " + quantCaixas );
  });
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Tente</button>
```

```
buttonBuy.addEventListener("click", () => {
let name= "nome";
let preco = 45.5;
let quantidade =  quantidadeunidades.value;
let quantCaixas = quantidadecaixas.value;
    alert("Comprar:" + name + "\nPreço" + preco + "\nQuantidade de Unidades" + quantidade  + "\nQuantidade de Caixas" + quantCaixas );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Vinicius,

Concatenar valores, basta colocar o mais (**+**) como você fez, para exibir em outra linha, você deve usar o **\n**.

Existe uma forma bem legal de colocar variáveis em uma string, trata-se do template string:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Também, existe o método concat da String do JS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

```js
let buttonConcat = document.getElementById("alertaConcat");
let buttonStringConcat = document.getElementById("alertaStringConcat");
let buttonTemplate = document.getElementById("alertaTemplate");

//Concatenção simples
buttonConcat.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let name = "teste";
  let preco = 13;
  let quantidadeunidades = {value: 10};
  let quantidadecaixas = {value: 5};

  alert("Comprar: " + name + ".\nPreço: " + preco + ".\nQuantidade de Unidades: " + quantidadeunidades.value + "\nQuantidade de Caixas: " + quantidadecaixas.value);
});

//Concatenção via método
buttonStringConcat.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let name = "teste";
  let preco = 13;
  let quantidadeunidades = {value: 10};
  let quantidadecaixas = {value: 5};

  alert("Comprar: ".concat(name, ".\nPreço: ", preco, ".\nQuantidade de Unidades: ", quantidadeunidades.value, "\nQuantidade de Caixas: ", quantidadecaixas.value));
});

//Template string
buttonTemplate.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let name = "teste";
  let preco = 13;
  let quantidadeunidades = {value: 10};
  let quantidadecaixas = {value: 5};

  alert(`Comprar: ${name}.\nPreço: ${preco}.\nQuantidade de Unidades: ${quantidadeunidades.value}.\nQuantidade de Caixas: ${quantidadecaixas.value}`);
});
```

```html
<button id="alertaConcat">Alerta concatenação</button>
<button id="alertaStringConcat">Alerta concatenação via método</button>
<button id="alertaTemplate">Alerta template strings</button>
```

Veja que em ambos os casos, eu utilizei do \n para efetuar a quebra de linha.

*Obs.: Segui parte do seu exemplo e criei as variáveis locais apenas para exemplificar.*

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta então o que você quer fazer é formatar uma string. Existem varias formas de fazer isso, uma bem conveniente é usar template strings:

Basicamente você pode criar uma usando um par de acento grave (``) ao invés de aspas simples ou aspas duplas. dentro destra string você pode colocar expresses seguindo a seguinte sintaxe:
`${expressao}`

Essa pode ser qualquer expressão, inclusive o valor de uma variável.

Neste caso o código ficaria assim:

```js
buttonBuy.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert(`Comprar: ${name}\nPreço: ${preco}\nQuantidade de Unidades: ${quantidadeunidades.value}\nQuantidade de Caixas: ${quantidadecaixas.value}`);
  });
```

Você pode aprender mais sobre formatação de texto em Javascript no site da Mozilla: [Formatando texto - MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Formatando_texto)